# Lodash sort list of objects based on key

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I am looking for sorting the list of objects based on key

Here is my object

```
var Categories =    {

      "social": [
        {
          "id": "social_001",
          "lastModified": "2 Day ago"
        }
      ],
"communication": [
        {
          "id": "communication_001",
          "lastModified": "4 Day ago"
        },
        {
          "id": "communication_002",
          "lastModified": "1 Day ago"
        }
      ],
      "storage": [
        {
          "id": "storage_001",
          "lastModified": "3 Day ago"
        }
      ]
    }
```

so in output sorted object will sort as start with **communication**,
       **social** ,
       **storage**
suggest me some help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort JavaScript object by key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key)

Comment: @MartinSchneider  I am looking solution using  lodash

Comment: from the linked Question: 'JavaScript objects are not ordered. It is meaningless to try to "sort" them. '

Comment: @MartinSchneider That's been changed in ES2015. String keys will iterate in creation order.

Comment: i stand corrected: in es2015 the keys will iterate in creation order, @Matt is right.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a solution using lodash:

```
var Categories = {
  "social": [
    {
      "id": "social_001",
      "lastModified": "2 Day ago"
    }
  ],
  "communication": [
    {
      "id": "communication_001",
      "lastModified": "4 Day ago"
    },
    {
      "id": "communication_002",
      "lastModified": "1 Day ago"
    }
  ],
  "storage": [
    {
      "id": "storage_001",
      "lastModified": "3 Day ago"
    }
  ]
}

var ordered = {};   
_(Categories).keys().sort().each(function (key) {
  ordered[key] = Categories[key];
});

Categories = ordered;
```

Comment: lodash actually ends up not much different to the native code for this `Object.keys(Categories).sort().forEach(key => o[key] = Categories[key])`. Even if you use `.reduce` both are still the same!

Answer (score 3):

Get the key array from your object using lodash `_.keys` or `Object.keys` and sort that array using JavaScript's `sort()` or `sort().reverse()` for ascending or descending order.

Then use this array for picking up each object by 
`yourObject[array[0]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner using lodash:

```js
_.pick(obj, Object.keys(obj).sort());
```

`pick` will return a new object with the keys in the order specified by the second argument.